# How to include scripts in <head>

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, header

Ok I am having a hard time with this one. I just inherited a 3.8.x Joomla site and all I'm trying to do is include a GTM script in the head of the document. What's happening is that anything within script tags or injected via $document->addScript(''); will be moved down to the end of the document.

How can I simply include a script tag in the head, and prevent it from being moved to the footer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default Joomla behaviour is to add scripts to the head element.

Try looking where `<jdoc:include type="head" />` appears in your template (under template/YOURTEMPLATE/index.php) - it may have been moved to the footer here.

Likewise, it might be a plugin which is moving the scripts to the footer, so you might want to review which have been installed.

A Google tells me that there is one called ScriptsDown, so it could well be that.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I DID have the ScriptsDown plugin installed, although it didn't show up the first time I searched for it in my early exploration of this issue. I'm guessing I had a typo.

Anyways, this was the issue. Disabling this plugin fixed my problem; thanks for your help!